# Print a string which has the reverse order

Tags: python, string, split, reverse

Assignment:

> Print a string which has the reverse order
> `'Python love We. Science Data love We'`

I tried this:

```
strg = We love Data Science. We love Python
words = strg.split(" ") 
words.reverse()
new_strg = " ".join(words)
print(new_strg)

>>> Python love We Science. Data love We
```

But the answer isn't as expected because the `.` after `Science` is not at the proper place.

How to get the expected result?

Comment: I'd split by '.' first.

Comment: What would the output be for *`We love Data Science (with passion!), but not debugging!?"*

Comment: Your code treats `"Science."` like one single item in an original string.  You want it to be two separate semantic entities, treated differently than space-separated words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the output you need?

```
Python love We. Science Data love We
```

Then the code is

```
strg = 'We love Data Science. We love Python'
pos = len(strg) - strg.index('.') - 2
words = [e.strip('.') for e in strg.split()]
words.reverse()
new_strg = ' '.join(words)
print(new_strg[:pos] + '.' + new_strg[pos:])
```

Or another way to do it:

```
strg = 'We love Data Science. We love Python'
new_strg = [s.split()[::-1] for s in strg.split('.')][::-1]
print(' '.join(new_strg[0]) + '. ' + ' '.join(new_strg[1]))
#or
print('{}. {}'.format(' '.join(new_strg[0]), ' '.join(new_strg[1])))
```

Or to raise the bar:

```
strg = 'We love Data Science. We love Python'
print('. '.join([' '.join(new_strg.split()[::-1]) for new_strg in strg.split('.')[::-1]]))
```

Comment: May you explain the meaning of this `pos = len(strg) - strg.index('.') - 2`

Comment: When subtracting current position from total positions, I should get the position in reverse order. However, the original index starts from zero, so subtract 1. And the position needs to be next to 'W', so subtract 1 more (ie, subtract 2)

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Can be done this way:

```
In [1]: s = "We love Data Science. We love Python"

In [2]: ". ".join(
    [" ".join(reversed(item.split())) for item in reversed(s.split("."))]
)
Out[2]: 'Python love We. Science Data love We'
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples:

```
Input :  "We love Python"
Output : "Python love We"  
Input :  "We love Data Science"
output : "Science Data love We"
```

reverse the words in the given string program

```
string = "We love Python"
s = string.split()[::-1]
l = []
for i in s:
    l.append(i)
print(" ".join(l))
```

or more simplest code:

```
string = "We love Python"
print(" ".join(string.split()[::-1]))
```

output:

```
Python love We
```